# Find free tag numbers in SQL: How to find multiple numbers in a row for SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to find free tag numbers in a SQL Server database. I have done this by declaring all possible tag numbers, and when a tag number is taken, it has a bit column that is set to 1. In other words, free tag numbers have BIT = 0.

```
SELECT TOP(\*NUMBERS*) TAG 
FROM \*DATABASE* 
WHERE BIT = 0
```

*NUMBERS* is how many tags I need. The problem is after some tag numbers are deleted, and I am trying to get e.g. 5 tag numbers i a row (e.g. 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15) I might get a spread of values (e.g. 5, 8, 10, 11, 12). I want to be able to reuse deleted tag numbers, but I want every numbers to be in a row.

How could I solve this in best practice (in SQL or C#)?

Comment: So your question is "How do I sort results in SQL?"

Comment: You have added two tags to your question _MySql_ and _sql-server_ Could you be more precise when asking this kind of question? The sql language implementation in not the same in every database on earth. Perhaps there are different answers for different databases

Comment: john: No, not like “order by …”, but every tag numbers should be one more than the previous number. So from the example tried to explain in the original post: 10,11,12,13,14,15 is what I want, but 5,8,10,11,12 is not what I want because 8 is 5+3 and not 5+1 and 10 is not 8+1. So in this case, 5 and 8 should have been filtered out, because the next needed numbers are not free.

Steve:
Sorry, I mean SQL-server.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not tested, but this query should give you the first tag of a sequence of NUMBERS free tags. The Idea should be clear...

```
SELECT TOP (1) TAG FROM *DATABASE* D WHERE BIT = 0 AND *NUMBERS* = (SELECT 
COUNT(*) FROM *DATABSE*  WHERE BIT = 0 AND TAG >= D.TAG AND TAG < D.TAG + *NUMBERS*)
```